# Getting the Last Row of a DataGridView and Storing it to a List or array

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, foreach

I have a DataGridView `dgv1` and I will be populating it 1 row at a time.

Every time a row is created, the created row will be stored in a List or Array.

```
private void dgvScanLogs_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        //List<string> sqlLog = dgvScanLogs.Rows[dgvScanLogs.Rows.Count - 1];

        //List<string> LogList = dgvScanLogs.Rows
        //                .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
        //                .Select(r => r.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
        //                .ToList();

    }
```

I have some code however, cant seem to get it right.
What I've made is getting the 1st Column to List, but I need the Last Row.

How can I store the Last/New Row to an `Array` or `List`?

Comment: Can you try re-framing your question? From your code, `List` you defined belongs to local scope, so will be lost after method execution completed.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, any variable declared with in method's scope will be ***lost***  after execution, it is the case in your program.

I assume, you want to store *every* added rows *first* `Cell` value.

Define `LogList` as class variable.

```
List<string> LogList = new List<string>();
```

[`RowsAdded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded(v=vs.110).aspx) event will be triggered for every new row added, so what you need is everytime when this event invoked update your list.

```
void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    LogList.Add(row[0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I need the whole row. But yes that works, I guess I just need to loop that using a for loop.

Comment: You mean, you need all columns?

Comment: Well, technically the whole row record from column 1 to column N.

Comment: You mean, all columns data in one string? or entire `DataGridViewRow` ?

Comment: All the column data in a `List<string>`. Listed inside the `List` is Column1 to Column N.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want. It looks like you're trying to add the last row to a locally defined `List` which would go out of scope as soon as your `RowsAdded` handler returns, but whatever:

```
List<string> sqlLog = new List<string>();
sqlLog.Add(dgvScanLogs.Rows[dgvScanLogs.Rows.Count - 1].ToString());
```

You need to create the `List` before you can add to it. And the `Item[Int32]` method on `DataGridViewRowCollection` doesn't return a list, so you need to add it to an existing list.

Comment: Yes yes, on `RowsAdded` the last row will stored in a List/Array for processing. Then if another Row is added, the List value will be replaced/overwritten not appended. I need the cell values of the row.

Comment: Nothing will be replaced/overwritten or appended because your `List` is a local variable. It will be a new empty list on each method call. Do you want each Cell to be an element in the list?